# EF code-first mapping complex type relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a base class for objects that are audited:

**AuditableObject**

```
public class AuditableObject : DomainObject, IAuditable
{
    ... some fields

   public AuditInfo AuditInfo
   {
        get;
        set;
   }
}
```

**AuditInfo**

```
public class AuditInfo : IAuditable
{

    public int CreatedByDbId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime CreatedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? AmendedByDbId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime? AmendedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The CreatedByDbId and AmendedByDbId are linked to a SystemUser object:

**SystemUser**

```
public class SystemUser
{
    public int SystemUserDbId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I have a class **Call** that inherits from AuditableObject, which also has other SystemUser properties:

```
public class Call : AuditableObject
{
    ... some fields

    public SystemUser TakenBy { get; set;}
    public SystemUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public SystemUser CancelledBy { get; set;}
    public int CancelledByDbId {get; set;}
    public int TakenByDbId { get; set;}
}
```

**Call database table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Call](
[CallDbId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CancelledBy] [int] NULL,
[CreatedByDbId] [int] NOT NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[AmendedByDbId] [int] NULL,
[AmendedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[TakenBy] [int] NOT NULL)
```

I cannot seem to get my mappings right, e.g.

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<AuditInfo>();
...// configuration for Call
this.Property(x => x.AuditInfo.AmendedByDbId).HasColumnName("AmendedByDbId");
this.Property(x => x.AuditInfo.AmendedDate).HasColumnName("AmendedDate");
this.Property(x => x.AuditInfo.CreatedByDbId).HasColumnName("CreatedByDbId");
this.Property(x => x.AuditInfo.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate");

this.Property(t => t.CancelledByDbId).HasColumnName("CancelledBy");
this.Property(t => t.TakenByDbId).HasColumnName("TakenBy");

this.HasRequired(t => t.TakenBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.TakenByDbId);
this.HasRequired(t => t.CancelledBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CancelledByDbId);
```

and I always get errors at runtime, such as:

```
Invalid column name 'SystemUser_SystemUserDbId'.
Invalid column name 'SystemUser_SystemUserDbId1'.
Invalid column name 'SystemUser_SystemUserDbId2'.
Invalid column name 'CreatedBy_SystemUserDbId'.
```

I can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last error **"Invalid column name 'CreatedBy_SystemUserDbId'"** could occur because there is missing a mapping of the `CreatedBy` navigation property to the `CreatedByDbId` foreign key column in the database. It should look like this:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.CreatedBy)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(c => c.MapKey("CreatedByDbId"));
```

I don't know the reason for the other three errors at the moment.

**Edit**

Taking a closer look I have the feeling that this model will be really difficult or perhaps impossible to map.

- You have a navigation property `CreatedBy` on the class `Call` but the foreign key property `CreatedByDbId` on a complex type `AuditInfo` of the base class `AuditableObject`. I have doubt that you can define in the mapping that these properties belong together in the same relationship to `SystemUser`.
- Therefore the navigation property `CreatedBy` should be in `AuditInfo` where the foreign key `CreatedByDbId` is. But that's not possible because you cannot put a navigation property into a complex type.
- Is it necessary to use a complex type for `AuditInfo`? Can't you put its properties directly into the `AuditableObject`:

  ```
  public class AuditableObject : DomainObject, IAuditable
  {
      ... some fields

      public int CreatedByDbId { get; set; }
      public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
      public int? AmendedByDbId { get; set; }
      public DateTime? AmendedDate { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- If you do this you should be able to move the `CreatedBy` navigation property from the `Call` entity to the `AuditableObject` base class where the FK `CreatedByDbId` lives and then create the same mapping you already did for the other two navigation properties, but this time for the base class:

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<AuditableObject>()
      .HasRequired(a => a.CreatedBy)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(a => a.CreatedById);
  ```